# Changing column values for a value in an adjacent column in the same dataframe using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am quite new to Python programming.
I am working with the following dataframe:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNy96.png)

Note that in column "FBgn", there is a mix of FBgn and FBtr string values. I would like to replace the FBtr-containing values with FBgn values provided in the adjacent column called "## FlyBase_FBgn". However, I want to keep the FBgn values in column "FBgn". Maybe keep in mind that I am showing only a portion of the dataframe (reality: 1432 rows). How would I do that? I tried the replace() method from Pandas, but it did not work.
This is actually what I would like to have:

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJh1N.png)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do post your samples in form of text in your question. Also please do post your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With Pandas, you could try:

```py
df.loc[df["FBgn"].str.contains("FBtr"), "FBgn"] = df["## FlyBase_FBgn"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Please next time provide more info including your code. It is always helpful

Please see the code below, I think you need something similar

```
import pandas as pd
#ignore the dict1, I just wanted to recreate your df
dict1= {"FBgn": ['FBtr389394949', 'FBgn3093840', 'FBtr000025'], "FBtr": ['FBgn546466646', '', 'FBgn15565555']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1) #recreating your dataframe
#print df
print(df)
```

[image]

```
#function to replace the values
def replace_values(df):
    for i in range(0, (df.size//2)):
        if 'tr' in df['FBgn'][i]:
            df['FBgn'][i] = df['FBtr'][i]
    return df
df = replace_values(df)

#print new df
print(df)
```

[image]